# Using bootstrap to make image centered vertical and horizontal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a page that is displaying content using bootstrap and I've gotten most of it about where I want it, except that my images, even though centered vertically, are not centered horizontally.

I'm trying to make it so that if someone adds a small image or a huge image, that it is always contained in the column/row and is responsive to that container, but I also want to make sure that if the image is smaller than the container that it sits perfectly in the middle of that container.

What am I missing here to make sure that an image is centered and middle aligned unless specified otherwise?

```
    html,
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    iframe{
      height:100% !important;
      width:100% !important;
    }

    .middle p{
      max-height:100%;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%; 
      height:auto;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .my-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      width:100vw;
    }

    .my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
    .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
      background-color: #778899  ;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .my-container>.middle {
      flex-grow: 1;
      padding:30px;
      /*background-image: url('images/bg_green.svg');*/
      background-size: cover;
    }

<div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
        <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%; ">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update:

Here's an image of the current situation (image is too high, though vertically centered) and the output I'm trying to achieve (no matter image size it is centered both vertically and horizontally)
[image]

UPDATE:

Multiple DIVS

```
.topLeftContent{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }
    .bottomLeftContent{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }
    .rightQtrContent{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }
```

```
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="rightColumnQtrHalf" >
        <div id="rightQtrContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below link. This might help you. I have added flex property to the parent div. thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/fzod273t/15/`enter`

Comment: That got it, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, actually: I just added an update above with multiple divs, can you tell me why it doesn't work for those? The images aren't centered or middle aligned for those

Comment: .(dot) is used for class and #(hash) is used for id. change dot to # it will work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried
`display: block`
 for image

if you can give a drawing of the layout you are looking to archive it helps

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't resolve it, but I added an image above in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image at center by add class col-lg-3 instead of col-lg-12 and give the div tag style is margin:0px auto to make it at center

```
<div class="col-lg-3" id="fullColumn" style="margin: 0px auto;">
    <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%; ">

    </div>
</div>
```